# Cannot connect to EC2 Instance through HTTP

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having trouble accessing my website through HTTP with an EC2 instance. I've tried changing the security setting by allowing HTTP on port 80, but it still doesn't work. SSH however is working fine. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is embarrassing, but the reason I couldn't connect to my EC2 instance was because my node js app never actually started a server for me to listen on port 80.

Adding this simple snippet of code

```
var server = app.listen(8080, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log('Example app listening, host, port)

})
```

Along with this shell command for redirecting fixed the issue.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Could check ip-tables if it is blocking 80, check the security group if the TCP for PORT 80 is open to your IP address or ( 0.0.0.0/0 ).

Given that you are able to SSH but not http, check if you can replicate the same settings in the SG which has the config for SSH 22 - also kindly look if the web-server ( or process ) is up and running in PORT 80.

Comment: The firewall is turned off. The security group has the TCP set as 80 for HTTP for all addresses. How would I check if the webserver is up and running in PORT 80?

Comment: assuming you are running httpd -> if you SSH you can try [ service httpd status ] -> this would return something like [ httpd (pid  23569) is running... ]

Answer (score 0):

First, login that instance, and run the command to confirm http service is running.

```
telnet INSTANCE_public_DNS_name 80
```

Then run the same command for your remote machine to confirm if there are any firewall issues.

If there is problem to telnet, then click the instance name, and go to `description` --> Security groups --> view rules.

You should see the port opened. If not, create a new security group or edit exist security groups, and assign to that instance.

Comment: The telnet command on my local machine gave the output `Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host` and on my remote machine `telnet: connect to address *: Connection refused`

Comment: Then you need make the web service running first.